# Unable to connect to a data base in mongo db from power BI

Tags: mongodb, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

Getting the following error:

```
DataSource.Error: ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 1.0(a) Driver][mysqld-5.7.12 mongosqld v2.6.0-beta3]Unknown database ''
Details:
    DataSourceKind=Odbc
    DataSourcePath=dsn=DigitalTeam
    OdbcErrors=Table
```

As shown [in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXyWU.jpg) the error arise as i am trying to get the data from Reports collection from test Database. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Unknown-database-error-when-connecting-to-MongoDB-with-ODBC/td-p/482364

Answer (score 0):

Per the comment by CodeCaster the most likely scenario of you getting a successful connection but not loading actual data is the fact you may have not selected a db from the dropdown when setting up the ODBC driver

After you setup your connection and port go to the last choice of Database: and select a db in the dropdown from the available list of db's in your environment.

Then when setting up the excel sheet for use of the ODBC data, via the data tab, choose your collection and documents from that collection should load.